# ionic in-app browser adding "http" protocol to play store intent url

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-intent, prepend

url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.i3v.edu.psc'
window.open(url, '_blank');

once after redirecting to the browser from ionic app.
The browser trying to open in playstore but http is added before the intent url hence throwing the error.

we have tried resolving by changing
url = 'https://play.app.goo.gl/?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.i3v.edu.psc'

and

url = '//market://details?id=com.i3v.edu.psc'

But nothing worked. Any help on this is appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZrfx.jpg)